# which hard drive will work better for an ip-camera DVR

Tags: hard-drive

This hard drive will be put in a DVR that records video from a few IP cameras. I found both of the following drives for about $80 each and would like to know which one would work the best.

2TB Caviar Green 5400RPM SATA 3Gb/s Intellipower 64 MB Cache (WD20EARS)

or a

1.5TB Seagate Barracuda 7200RPM SATA 3Gb/s 32MB cache (ST31500341AS)?

Does the extra cache make up for the slower spin speed?

Supposing the capacities were the same. what's more important, faster RPM or bigger cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the extra cache will not make up fro the slower spin speed, see this previous question:  [Hard Drive Speed: RPM vs. Cache](https://serverfault.com/questions/28608/hard-drive-speed-rpm-vs-cache)

Depending on the number of cameras and Frames Per Second you'll be recording at, the extra space may be more important than the spin speed on a DVR.

Comment: I agree with, Aaron. I would go with more space when you are talking video storage, if you must pick between speed or capacity.

Comment: The only deal is that both of these capacities are way more than they're used to. The DVR only records motion and anything over a TB will be gravy. Probably should edit the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read the difference between 32 and 64MB or cache on a hard drive is moot. Western Digital Blacks are right around your price range and size and have better speed than the greens.